# Create array out of all images in app?

Tags: ios, arrays, image, bundle

Is it possible to create a NSArray out of all .png, .jpg, and .jpeg that are all in my app? I know it is possible to do it to a certain type like only .pngs but I am not sure how to do it to all images in my app.

I would rather not have lots of conditionals so how could I do this easily?

Thanks!

Edit1:

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
NSString * pathToImages = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/images", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
NSFileManager *localFileManager= [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [localFileManager enumeratorAtPath:pathToImages];
NSString *file;
NSLog(@"level1");
while (file = [dirEnum nextObject]) {
    NSLog(@"level2");
    if(file)
    {
        NSLog(@"level3");
        [imagesArray addObject:file];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you want to store images in your array.  Do you want file references or actual UIImage objects?

Anyways... if you kept all your images in a "images" folder in your app's Resources directory, why not try something like:

```
NSString * pathToImages = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/images", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
NSFileManager *localFileManager= [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [localFileManager enumeratorAtPath:docsDir];
NSMutableArray * arrayOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 1];
NSString *file;
while (file = [dirEnum nextObject]) {
    // let's assume that all objects in here are valid images
    UIImage * newImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: file];
    if(newImage)
    {
        [arrayOfImages addObject: newImage];
    }
}
```

By the way... if you are loading a lot of images (especially high rez ones), you're likely to hit [`didReceiveMemoryWarning`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didReceiveMemoryWarning) calls in your view controllers.

Comment: How would I do this with NSStrings? AKA the file references?

Comment: Then just do `[arrayOfImages addObject: file];` instead of creating a new `UIImage` object.  When the routine is done, you'll have an array of file references.

Comment: I wasn't certain if you were using ARC or not. Set a breakpoint at the `addObject` line and see if it hits there.  If the array is null, it sounds like never hits there.

Comment: I am not using ARC but I will check soon

Comment: I just added NSLogs checks which i show above and it doesn't even make it up to level2! Any ideas?

Comment: Yep... sounds like the directory enumeration isn't working at all (probably because there's no "images" folder in the built application).  If you look at the contents of your compiled & built app bundle, is there a "images" folder or are those images being kept somewhere else?

Comment: My images are in a 'Group' in Xcode but if I look at the compiled app bundle all the images are loose and not in any folder. So how would I make sure they are added to a folder unless I could do it from the group name in Xcode.

Comment: Put all your images into one folder in your source code tree, then when you drag that folder into XCode, make sure "Create Folder References for any added folders" radio button is set to **on**.  Then the images in that folder will get added, along with the folder itself, to your compiled app.